# Embed latest Instagram post to a PHP website

Tags: php, post, instagram, embed

I want to embed the latest updating post from Instagram profile in the website homepage. Now I can select a particular post in the profile and while embedding that on it shows in the site. But is there any way to get the latest one only without directly mentioning the post?

I tried to add a single post but when I tried the embed option from profile it only shows as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbPj1.png) no profile name or an thing related to it is not showing

Comment: What do you mean by "enter image description here?" Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Comment: There is no social plugin provided to automatically show a profile's latest post. You would have to get the latest post via API, so that you can then explicitly embed it via its specific post URL.